# How to retain same FLOAT value after converting it to a VARCHAR in Azure Synapse

Tags: type-conversion, varchar, floating-point, azure-synapse-analytics

Consider the following example:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.TEST_FLOAT;
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_FLOAT (
    AMOUNT    FLOAT
);
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_FLOAT (AMOUNT) VALUES (11546.25);
SELECT AMOUNT, CAST(AMOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) AS AMOUNT_AS_CHAR 
FROM dbo.TEST_FLOAT
```

This is what is returned from Management Studio:

[image]

What I want is the displayed values to be the same, however it seems Azure Synapse is rounding the number when the CAST is performed.

I need this to work inline as I am hashing several concatenated values and need these all COALESCED VARCHARS.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ergest Basha who answered this in a comment:

Here is the result:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.TEST_FLOAT;
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_FLOAT (
    AMOUNT    FLOAT
);
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_FLOAT (AMOUNT) VALUES (11546.25);
SELECT AMOUNT, 
       CAST(AMOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) AS AMOUNT_AS_CHAR,
       CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), AMOUNT, 128) AS AMOUNT_AS_CHAR2
FROM dbo.TEST_FLOAT
```

This is now working in AMOUNT_AS_CHAR2

[image]

**UPDATE**

I just discovered this solution DOES NOT WORK when the amount is ZERO. My work around is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.TEST_FLOAT;
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_FLOAT (
    AMOUNT    FLOAT
);
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_FLOAT (AMOUNT) VALUES (11546.25);
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_FLOAT (AMOUNT) VALUES (0.0);
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_FLOAT (AMOUNT) VALUES (-0.1);
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_FLOAT (AMOUNT) VALUES (2.0);
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_FLOAT (AMOUNT) VALUES (NULL);

SELECT AMOUNT, 
       CAST(AMOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) AS AMOUNT_AS_CHAR,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AMOUNT, 128) AS AMOUNT_AS_CHAR2,
       CASE [AMOUNT] WHEN 0 THEN '0' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(59), [AMOUNT], 128) END AS AMOUNT_AS_CHAR3
FROM dbo.TEST_FLOAT
```

Adding the INLINE CASE wrapper gets around the issue...

[image]

Comment: Note that conversion style 128 [is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#float-and-real-styles)